# designing interface for choosing between two images

Tags: image, hci

This is a general question about HCI. I was wondering what are some of the best examples of UIs you've seen that presents a user two images and has them choose which one of them is better. I have several thousand image pairs and I was looking to make the most intuative and fun way for users to go through these pairs while choosing the better image of the two.

My goals are:

1- to have them vote/choose the better image out of the pair

2- keep them curious about the upcoming pairs and

3- to give them some sort of progress/reward for going through as many pairs as possible

My first thought was an automated cover flow like UI where each item is an image pair, clicking on the one you like automatically scrolls you over to the next pair. This would allow the user to see that there are more pairs coming up and that they're making progress

[image: draft sketch]

Answer (score 2):

I think that's an excellent interface. Possible enhancements:

- Allow users to skip when they have no significant preference. You could have 'Skip to These' appear as a hover when you point at a future image pair.
- Dynamically slide the images into and out of the selection box, rather than snapping. It's harder to see the flow when images snap to new positions.
- Progress bar or some way to show how far along the 1000+ pairs they are.